# Is there any way to add new launch image from terminal for Xcode

Tags: xcode

In the Assests.xcassets folder, I need to add a new iOS launch image, otherwise it won't let me build. However I am trying to do this in terminal, is there any command does that?

Answer (score 0):

Apple has some [documentation on the format of asset catalogs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/FolderStructure.html). You can generate relevant JSON and write to any *.xcassets folder.